# Приложение не запускается

Tags: java, android

Уже 3 дня мучаюсь... Я создавал табы отдельно и recyclerView отдельно, теперь обьединил. Запускаю не запускается Unfortunately!!! В чем может быть проблема?

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_action_person,
        R.drawable.ic_action_group,
        R.drawable.ic_action_call
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new TabOneFragment(), "One");
    adapter.addFragment(new TabTwoFragment(), "Two");
    adapter.addFragment(new TabThreeFragment(), "Three");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

**TabOneFragment:**

```
public class TabOneFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_one_fragment, container, false);

    recyclerview = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<TicketObjects> items = new ArrayList<>();

    RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(items);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);

}

}
```

**RVAdapter:**

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

private List<TicketObjects> mItems;


public RVAdapter(List<TicketObjects> mItems) {
    this.mItems = mItems;

}

public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView departCode;
    TextView departTime;
    TextView departDate;
    TextView arriveCode;
    TextView arriveTime;
    TextView arriveDate;
    TextView flyTime;
    Button ticketPrice;
    ImageView airlineLogo;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        departCode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAirCodeDepart);
        departTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDepartTime);
        departDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDepartDate);
        arriveCode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCodeArrive);
        arriveTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvArriveTime);
        arriveDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvArriveDate);
        flyTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        ticketPrice = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnTickPrice);
        airlineLogo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivAirlineLogo);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) {

    itemViewHolder.departCode.setText(mItems.get(i).getDepartCode());
    itemViewHolder.departTime.setText(mItems.get(i).getDepartTime());
    itemViewHolder.departDate.setText(mItems.get(i).getDepartDate());
    itemViewHolder.arriveCode.setText(mItems.get(i).getArriveCode());
    itemViewHolder.arriveTime.setText(mItems.get(i).getArriveTime());
    itemViewHolder.arriveDate.setText(mItems.get(i).getArriveDate());
    itemViewHolder.flyTime.setText(mItems.get(i).getFlyTime());
    itemViewHolder.ticketPrice.setText(mItems.get(i).getTicketPrice());
    itemViewHolder.airlineLogo.setImageResource(mItems.get(i).getAirlineLogo());
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, viewGroup, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}
}
```

**TicketsObjects**

```
public class TicketObjects {

private String departCode;
private String departTime;
private String departDate;
private String arriveCode;
private String arriveTime;
private String arriveDate;
private String flyTime;
private String ticketPrice;
private int airlineLogo;

public TicketObjects(String departCode, String departTime, String departDate,
                     String arriveCode, String arriveTime, String arriveDate,
                     String flyTime, String ticketPrice, int airlineLogo) {


    this.departCode = departCode;
    this.departTime = departTime;
    this.departDate = departDate;
    this.arriveCode = arriveCode;
    this.arriveTime = arriveTime;
    this.arriveDate = arriveDate;
    this.flyTime = flyTime;
    this.ticketPrice = ticketPrice;
    this.airlineLogo = airlineLogo;
}

public String getDepartCode(){
    return departCode;
}


public void setDepartCode(String departCode){
    this.departCode = departCode;
}

public String getDepartTime(){
    return departTime;
}

public void setDepartTime(String departTime){
    this.departTime = departTime;
}

public String getDepartDate(){
    return departDate;
}

public void setDepartDate(String departDate){
    this.departDate = departDate;
}

public String getArriveCode(){
    return arriveCode;
}

public void setArriveCode(String arriveCode){
    this.arriveCode = arriveCode;
}

public String getArriveTime(){
    return arriveTime;
}

public void setArriveTime(String arriveTime){
    this.arriveTime = arriveTime;
}

public String getArriveDate(){
    return arriveDate;
}

public void setArriveDate(String arriveDate){
    this.arriveDate = arriveDate;
}

public String getFlyTime(){
    return flyTime;
}

public void setFlyTime(String flyTime){
    this.flyTime = flyTime;
}

public String getTicketPrice(){
    return ticketPrice;
}

public void setTicketPrice(String ticketPrice){
    this.ticketPrice = ticketPrice;
}

public int getAirlineLogo(){
    return airlineLogo;
}

public void setAirlineLogo(int airlineLogo){
    this.airlineLogo = airlineLogo;
}

}
```

**Error:**

```
.recyclerview.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ, твой ответ оказывается был близок...

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionBarColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/titleBarColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: NoActionBar не был указан?

Comment: да. И WindowNoTitle тоже...

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка же очевидно говорит, что в Ваш стиль надо добавить итем `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`

Comment: Добавил, ничего не меняется

Comment: на лолипопе запускаете?

Comment: Нет на Сендвиче

Comment: Экшнбар такой? android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

Comment: и прикрепите styles.xml и разметку тулбара тоже